# java.lang.InstantiationError when mocking method with interface as generic type in Kotlin using Mockk

Tags: spring, kotlin, jpa, generics, mockk

I am using Kotlin 1.7.10 and Mockk 1.12.4 and I have a factory method in the following spring bean class:

```
@Service
class DataSynchronizationManagerFactoryService(
    private val platformTransactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager
) {
    fun <D : DataDto, E : DbEntity, R : DataSynchronizableRepository<E>> constructDataSynchronisationManager(
        processedEntityType: Class<E>,
        repository: R,
        dataLoaderAndTransformer: DataLoaderAndTransformer<D, E>
    ): DataSynchronisationManager<D, E, R> {
        return DataSynchronisationManager<D, E, R>(
            processedEntityType,
            repository,
            dataLoaderAndTransformer,
            TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager)
        )
    }
}
```

where `D`, `E` and `R` are the following respective interfaces:

```
public interface DataDto {
    String getSystemId();

}

public interface DbEntity {
    String getSystemId();
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface DataSynchronizableRepository<T extends DbEntity> extends
        JpaRepository<T, String>,
        BatchPersistableRepository<T> {

    void deleteBySystemIdIn(Collection<String> systemIds);
}
```

I am attempting to mock call to the `constructDataSynchronisationManager` method using Mockk:

```
every {
    dataSynchronizationManagerFactoryServiceMock
        .constructDataSynchronisationManager<DataDto, DbEntity, DataRepository>(
            any(),
            any(),
            any(),
        )
} returns dataSynchronisationManagerMock
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationError: com.andrew.DataRepository

    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ObjenesisInstantiator.instanceViaObjenesis(ObjenesisInstantiator.kt:75)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ObjenesisInstantiator.instance(ObjenesisInstantiator.kt:42)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmInstantiator$instantiate$2.invoke(JvmInstantiator.kt:16)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractInstantiator.instantiateViaInstanceFactoryRegistry(AbstractInstantiator.kt:17)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmInstantiator.instantiate(JvmInstantiator.kt:15)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState$matcher$signatureValue$1$1.invoke(RecordingState.kt:49)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmAnyValueGenerator$anyValue$2.invoke(JvmAnyValueGenerator.kt:35)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AnyValueGenerator.anyValue(AnyValueGenerator.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmAnyValueGenerator.anyValue(JvmAnyValueGenerator.kt:31)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState$matcher$signatureValue$1.invoke(RecordingState.kt:48)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.JvmSignatureValueGenerator.signatureValue(JvmSignatureValueGenerator.kt:20)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.matcher(RecordingState.kt:47)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.matcher(CommonCallRecorder.kt:52)
```

If I create an actual implementation of the DataRepository:

```
class DataRepositoryImpl: DataRepository<...> {
    // provide empty implementation of all methods
}
```

and then use the `DataRepositoryImpl` in the `every` block to simulate the behavior, the mock goes through, but it is suboptimal because it does not represent the actual code.

Is there a way to mock the call to the generic method so that the `InstantiationError` does not happen?

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/832

Comment: @philonous, thank you for the suggestion. I dove a bit deeper into the problem and found it is a bug in the library, which I reported here: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/865. I provided more info there.